# db.collection.find().explain() no longer outputs performance details in MongoDB 4.0

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I created a collection of 10 000 unique phone numbers.

Without creating my own index, I use the following query:

```
db.phones.find({display: "+7 800-5550018"}).explain()
```

MongoDB performs a collection scan and I get the return:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mongoIntro.phones",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "display" : {
                                "$eq" : "+7 800-5550018"
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "display" : {
                                        "$eq" : "+7 800-5550018"
                                }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "----------------------------------",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "4.0.13",
                "gitVersion" : "bda366f0b0e432ca143bc41da54d8732bd8d03c0"
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1573842908, 2),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1573842908, 2),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"Xo5c5M9Yb2Y8f8ZMV2jpEwBUT3Y="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6758691052451790849")
                }
        }
}
```

Using `db.collection.find().explain()`, an older version of MongoDB produced an output that contained the number of milliseconds it took to return the query results as well as the number of scanned objects. Example)

```
{
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"nscanned" : 10999,
"nscannedObjects" : 10999,
"n" : 1,
"millis" : 52,
"indexBounds" : {
}
}
```

Is there a way to get a report about performance that includes at least milliseconds? The intention would be to compare performance of a collection scan vs. an indexed scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
db.collection.find().explain("executionStats")
```